# Python - Upload a file to an amazon lightsail instance

Tags: python, cloud, amazon-lightsail

This isn't a S3 instance.
It's a cloud server which pem files are required to SSH into.

The python script will be running on a linux machine.

Question is quite simple, I just need guidance or somewhere to start:

How can I upload a file to my lightsail instance using python?

Comment: what about a cron on the instance to sync an s3 bucket every minute?

Comment: `This isn't a S3 instance` - does lightsail use buckets? If it does I didn't know this!

Comment: in your lightsail instance. install awscli. use `aws s3 sync your-bucket /path/to.local`. now from your machine you can copy files to the bucket and lightsail will sync it every few minutes

Comment: This won't incur additional costs?

Comment: sync only copies if there are changes. your costs would be s3 storage and ingress.